# Accessing M-values associated to LINESTRING M and MULTILINESTRING M geometries

Tags: python, python-3.x, ogr, multilinestring, osgeo

How can I access a line geometry's multiple M-values? Consider that the line geometry in question can be either a LINESTRING M or MULTILINESTRING M geometry that was created using `osgeo`/`ogr`.

Here's a small reproducible example:

```py
from osgeo import ogr

line_wkt  = 'LINESTRING M (0 0 5, 0 1 6, 1 1 10)'
line_geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(line_wkt)


mline_wkt = 'MULTILINESTRING M ((0 0 5, 0 1 6, 1 1 10), (1 1 10, 2 1 20, 3 1 30))'
mline_geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(mline_wkt)
```

In the example above, the `line_geom` and `mline_geom` objects are successfully stored with their respective M-values, but I'm having a hard time accessing them.

I'm searching for a function that will return `[5,6,10]` for the `line_geom` object and `[[5,6,10],[10,20,30]]` for the `mline_geom` object.

Here are the alternatives I've tried but ultimately did not work:

#### Using the `GetM()` method

The `GetM()` method doesn't seem to give me exactly what I want. For example, when I do `line_geom.GetM()`, I just get back `5.0`. I think it just gives me the M-value for the first point in the line.

Also, when I try `line_geom.GetM()`, I get back `0.0` and then a bunch of `ERROR 6: Incompatible geometry for operation`.

#### Using the `GetPoints()` method

I thought I would be able to iterate over a line' points using the `GetPoints()` method and access the M-values through there. Unfortunately, that didn't work either - when I run `line_geom.GetPoints()`, the resulting list does not contain the M-values: `[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0)]`.

Also, when I try `mline_geom.GetPoints()`, I just get a bunch of `ERROR 6: Incompatible geometry for operation`.

#### Note

The solution needs to be in Python. I know that I can do a lot of stuff using `ogr2ogr`'s CLI, but this is a small part of something bigger and this needs to be in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [OGR Geometry docs](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html):

> `GetM(Geometry self, int point=0)`

By default, just calling `line_geom.GetM()` will return the measure for the first point - default `point=0` argument.

For the multilinestring, you need to get each individual geometry, before getting the points and measures.

```
line_wkt  = 'LINESTRING M (0 0 5, 0 1 6, 1 1 10)'
line_geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(line_wkt)

for i, point in enumerate(line_geom.GetPoints()):
    print(line_geom.GetM(i), point)


mline_wkt = 'MULTILINESTRING M ((0 0 5, 0 1 6, 1 1 10), (1 1 10, 2 1 20, 3 1 30))'
mline_geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(mline_wkt)

for j in range(mline_geom.GetGeometryCount()):
    geom = mline_geom.GetGeometryRef(j)
    for i, point in enumerate(geom.GetPoints()):
        print(geom.GetM(i), point)
```

Output:

```
5.0 (0.0, 0.0)
6.0 (0.0, 1.0)
10.0 (1.0, 1.0)
5.0 (0.0, 0.0)
6.0 (0.0, 1.0)
10.0 (1.0, 1.0)
10.0 (1.0, 1.0)
20.0 (2.0, 1.0)
30.0 (3.0, 1.0)
```