# Reading M-Values from shapefiles using GeoPandas/Fiona

Tags: gdal, geopandas, shapefile

I am working with a set of line features (roads) that are represented as "polyline ZM" in shapefiles. However, when using geopandas/fiona to read the shapefiles, the return geometry is always LineString Z. I read online that GDAL supports reading M-values from shapefiles.

I am wondering if there is a way I can load the M-values from shapefiles in python. Because so far I haven't had any luck in my googling, maybe I am just not looking into the right places.

(P.S. I prefer not to use arcpy if possible)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to check out gis.stackexchange.com. Also, when asking questions it is helpful to include both the code you tried and the results you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geopandas can't properly read geometries with M-values. This seems to be an upstream problem with the libraries that GeoPandas uses. See these github issue threads for more info:

- [GeoPandas/Reading in M values using geopandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2188)
- [Shapely/POINT M parsed as POINT Z](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/882)
- [Fiona/M Values in Shapefile aren't shown](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/774)

Sadly, it doesn't seem like it's getting fixed anytime soon.

If you want, you can also use the Python GDAL/OGR libraries. It is **SIGNIFICANTLY** more cumbersome than using GeoPandas, but it does support geometries with M-values. See the following links for more explicit examples on how to use them:

- [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html)
- [Accessing M-values associated to LINESTRING M and MULTILINESTRING M geometries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69443408/accessing-m-values-associated-to-linestring-m-and-multilinestring-m-geometries)
- [Creating Python OSGEO/OGR geometry with M-values (not using WKT)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413872/creating-python-osgeo-ogr-geometry-with-m-values-not-using-wkt)